How to cut out slightly complex shape from div (see through)?
I want to do a cutout in the shape of rounded triangle on both sides of a card. Also maybe add some kind of delimiter from the edge of the left rectangle to the edge of the right.
Basically I want to do this (an image is worth a 1000 words):

Now because of the delimiter requirement I need to have 2 divs (one for the upper part and one for the bottom part)
I can't just make a div with background color on top to fake a cut because I don't know what will be bellow the card and it has to be visible though the cut.

Frankly, use an SVG
